# SharePoint Retention Policies List

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell, retention

I am currently using SP 2010.

I have get the list of retention policies enabled sites and Document library / List in my site collection along with my retention period.

Can someone help me with a PowerShell script or any ideas on how to get the retention policy information on the above?

The output should include all the retention policy details on site level including document library and list with retention period.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it's not available to use PowerShell script to get retention policy information in the SharePoint 2010.

As a workaround, you could use “Generate file plan report” to export retention policy details at list and library level.

Reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/644e54/generate-file-plan-report-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365/

Comment: Thanks for ypur response. But we have to get the data for all the retention policies that are available in out sites . The output should be like a list of retention policies that are available in the site.

Is there any way to get the data .

Comment: I don't think it's possible.